# Efficient way to check if individual arrays inside a 2-d array have equal lengths

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say we have a 2D array 
`int[][] arr = new int[][] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7 }, { 8, 9 } };`

Here, `arr[1]` has a length of `3`.

Is there any efficient way to check if all the 1-d arrays present within the 2-d array have equal lengths?

Say, without looping through the array or may be through using any data structure which can be preferred instead of a `int[][]`?

Comment: Unless you preprocess the lengths in some efficient way, you can't avoid a loop somewhere - you need to inspect each element.

Comment: Thanks, Oliver. I was thinking of avoiding the inspection.

Comment: Nope, I can use any other data structure, say List<int[]> in place of int[][]

Comment: Where is the array coming from?

Comment: @xehpuk, consider we were given the 2d array as a parameter in some method. Or maybe we can ask for a specific data structure such as List<int[]> from the calling method.

Comment: You could encapsulate an `int[][]` in your own class (e.g. `IntArray2D` with the constructor taking two length parameters) to restrict the arrays to the same length.

Comment: @xehpuk, that would work for me. Any idea if we should keep additional constructors to prevent uneven lengths arrays from entering into the 2d array?

Comment: @DevendraLattu I'm afraid I don't understand your question. You would prevent the direct use of the underlying arrays. Instead, you would offer methods like `void set(int x, int y, int value)` and `int get(int x, int y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you do not do some bookkeeping at *construction time*, etc. you cannot avoid turning this into an *O(n)* algorithm with *n* the number of **rows**. For instance:

```
public static boolean sameLengths(int[][] matrix) {
    if(matrix == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if(matrix.length > 0) {
        if(matrix[0] == null) {
            return false;
        }
        int n = matrix[0].length;
        for(int[] row : matrix) {
            if(row == null || row.length != n) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The *edge-cases* are what to do with **`null` values** and what with a matrix with **no rows**. Here I decided that:

- a `null` matrix returns `false`;
- a matrix with a row equal to `null` returns `false` as well; and
- a matrix with no rows, returns `true` (since in that case all rows have the same length).

It is easy to alter the implementation if you to handle these edge-cases differently.

Comment: Thanks, Willem. It looks legit :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use java8, the below code (look at the inline comments) is much simpler, which uses basic `stream` (i.e., internal iteration) methods:

```
int[][] arr = new int[][] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4}, { 6, 7 }, { 8, 9 } }; 
final int[] firstSubArray = arr[0];//get the first array size
//Now with stream skip first element & check the size with rest
boolean isSubArraysSameSize = Arrays.stream(arr).//get stream from array
            skip(1).//skip first element
            allMatch(subArray -> 
              subArray.length == firstSubArray.length);//check rest all sizes match
System.out.println(isSubArraysSameSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

In comments you said that we can use a **List**. So, check the difference in length at the time of adding a new list. After that, getting an answer will cost `O(1):`

```
class DataWrapper {
    private List<List<Integer>> data = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Integer> lastAdded;
    private boolean isDifferentLength;

    public void add(List<Integer> newList) {
        if (data.add(newList)) {
            if (!isDifferentLength && isDifferentLengthWith(newList)) {
                 isDifferentLength = true;
            }
            lastAdded = newList;
        }
    }

    private boolean isDifferentLengthWith(List<Integer> newList) {
        return lastAdded != null && lastAdded.size() != newList.size();
    }

    public boolean isDifferentLength() {
        return isDifferentLength;
    }
}
```